# Grid artifacts when disabling linear filtering on bump map in Three.js

Tags: three.js, fragment-shader, bump-mapping

If the `magFilter` of a bump map in Three.js is set to `THREE.NearestFilter`, a weird grid artifact appears on the object. The grid's spacing is equivalent to the bump map pixels. As soon as the magFilter is put back to default (`THREE.LinearFilter`) everything is fine.

*I, however, need to disable filtering since I'm calculating a height value out of an RGB encoded height map.*

Interestingly, when trying out a random normal map, setting the `magFilter` to `NearestFilter` produces no such artifacts.

[image: bump map artifacts]

Tried this with and without shadow mapping, with various bump maps and normal maps.
Aim would be to get rid of them.

——

**EDIT: An example (not my code but for demonstration)** https://codepen.io/Mombasa/pen/ivdyC

With linear filtering, things look perfect:

[image]

Just by adding `bmap.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;` after line 14 – i.e., disabling linear filtering, the bump mapping gets kinda reduced to the *outlines* of the bump-mapping affected areas.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your code, or a working demo? At first glance it looks like your geometry's faces are splitting up, but hard to know for certain.

Comment: I edited the original post to include an example as well as further screenshots.